# Sockets packet forwarding

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I'm looking to create some kind of a gateway that sits between a server and a client.
The so called gateway is supposed to filter some packets sent by the client and forward 99% of them.

Here are my questions:

1. Client opens a new socket to the gateway, i open a socket to the server from the gateway and store it in a list for further use. However, in one situation, all the connections will come from the same IP, thus leaving me with limited options on choosing the socket that should forward the packet to the server. How can i differentiate between opened sockets?
2. From previous situations, i'm expecting about 500 clients sending a packet every second. Performance wise, should i use a multithread model, or stick with a single thread application?
3. Still a performance question :I have to choose between C# and Python. Which one should give better performance?

Answer (score 1):

Socket addresses are a host *and port*, not just a host. And different connections from the same host will always have different ports. (I'm assuming TCP, not UDP, here.)

Or, even more simply, you can just compare the file descriptors (or, in Python, the socket objects themselves) instead of their peer addresses.

Meanwhile, for performance, on most platforms, 500 is nearing the limits of what you can do with threads, but not yet over the limits, so you *could* do it that way. But I think you'll be better off with a single-threaded reactor or a proactor with a small thread pool. Especially if you can use a preexisting framework like twisted or gevents to do the hard part for you.

As for the language, for just forwarding or filtering packets, the performance of your socket multiplexing will be all that matters, so there's no problem using Python. Pick a framework you like from either language, and use that language.

Some last side comments: you do realize that TCP packets aren't going to match up with messages in your higher level protocol(s), right? Also, this whole thing would probably be a lot easier to do, and more efficient, with a Linux or BSD box set up as a router so you don't have to write anything but the filters.

Comment: The authentication of the client is done via it's socket descriptor on the server, and there's no higher level protocols.

On the 1% of the packets i'll have to do some database checks, and i don't want any major delays in the flow.

Comment: @your_average_programmer: how could there be no higher level protocols? What are you using the sockets for if the data don't mean anything?